# Hmisc::describe not working with dataframe

Tags: r

I need a "describe" function that reports values with more than two decimal places and so I thought I would use the Hmisc describe function but even when using the sample code from http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/Hmisc/docs/describe I get an error:

```
> dfr <- data.frame(x=rnorm(400),y=sample(c('male','female'),400,TRUE))
> Hmisc::describe(dfr)
Error in UseMethod("describe") : 
  no applicable method for 'describe' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
> psych::describe(dfr)
   vars   n mean   sd median trimmed  mad   min  max range  skew kurtosis   se
x     1 400 0.07 0.96   0.07    0.07 0.94 -2.41 2.76  5.17  0.02     -0.3 0.05
y*    2 400 1.50 0.50   2.00    1.50 0.00  1.00 2.00  1.00 -0.01     -2.0 0.03
```

Any suggestions as to why it should be doing this?

Comment: If you try `methods(describe)`, do you see describe.data.frame? When I run the code you posted, it works fine. I would suggest clearing your environment/workspace, re-installing Hmisc, and trying again.

Comment: I get:
    > methods(describe)
    [1] describe.by
    Warning message:
    In methods(describe) : function 'describe' appears not to be generic
    > methods(Hmisc::describe)
    Error in methods(Hmisc::describe) : 
      no function 'Hmisc::describe' is visible

Comment: Does the same thing happen after running `install.packages('Hmisc')`? - if it does, you might want to try using the `devtools` package to download the source directly like so: `install_url('http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/contrib/3.1/Hmisc_3.14-5.tgz')` obviously change the url if you're not on mac.

Comment: you could use `Hmisc:::describe.data.frame(dfr)`, but then the print method isn't seen either so it just prints as a list.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `describe` in a way that is not supported.  Just use:

```
require(Hmisc)   # or library(Hmisc)
describe(mydataframe)
```

To get even better output install LaTeX and run

```
latex(describe(mydataframe), file='')
# file='' to put LaTeX code inline as for knitr
```

Comment: +1 though I think the OP was trying to avoid the conflict in function names with the `psych` package. It would explain why they're trying to use it the way they did.

Comment: Tried the usual of restarting RStudio, reloading etc. and it seems to be working "as advertised" now. Not sure what was wrong, probably me not being a big fan of R meant that I missed something. Unfortunately my original problem has not been solved (too few decimal places on the broad range of stats) so I have a loop instead to calculate them using single purpose functions.

Comment: describe(x, digits=6)